# Refusing New Job Proposal (Contract)

Tags: recruitment, hiring-process, rejection

I started a job interview process a month ago.

I was initially contacted by an intermediate recruiter which connected me with the actual potential employer later on.

During the first interview, I told my potential boss at the end of the interview that I had questions related to perks. His response was: "there will be a HR interview where you can ask such questions".

A couple of weeks later, I receive a phone stating that I am hired, and I need to provide my ID for the preparation of the contract.

I was surprised that the HR interview skipped, but then I decided to proceed rather than stall the process.

When I received the contract, and I discovered, after reading it, that some default perk was missing, and as I have been an employee for a decade, this perk was a prerequisite for me.

I asked over the phone the HR manager, who was very open and said they are planning to establish this perk using an alternative product, which is not good news for me.

Moreover, my situation changed, and it's in my advantage to spend more months with my current employer for personal reasons.

Therefore, my priorities changed.

Meanwhile, I discovered that I didn't negotiate my salary as I should.

Consequently, I decided to refuse this contract last Friday, first because of the missing perk, and second because my priorities changed.

Eventually, the recruiter contacted me today and told me that they have a problem because of my rejection.

I explained the reasons above, and I added that I realized that I am not ready to resign from my current position for such a minor salary raise with a missing perk.

I added that I sent my refusal explaination along with the rejection email. I only stated to the employer that my reason for refusing was related to the missing perk.

The recruiter told me that he is going to talk to this employer again about me, and he will mention that they should do something about the missing perk, and he will try to gracefully inject the fact that I would a better salary.

Did this recruiter contact me to hear my version to understand what went on actually?

Or did they contact me to refine the employer's proposal?

Or is there any other reason?

Comment: What is the perk? Can it be replaced with additional money? For a company, it may just be easier to give you more money, than to go through all the paperwork of doing a one-off perk.

Answer (score 6):

1. Recruiter would not get paid if you don't start.

On the other note:

Interview is a two sided process and lots of employers don`t get it.

It has been good for them for so long that no one is even considering that  employee can refuse offer and go somewhere else.

IMHO, you should not share any extraneous information, only one you decide is relevant to current level of interaction.

You decided that offer is insufficient and that what you say to HR or recruiter, if you like you can share details regarding where its lacking.

Comment: “Extraneous” information to me is anything the prospective employer has no control over. They can do something about the salary being too low or a perk missing. They can’t do anything about changes in personal situations, so if it were me, I would be very vague about those aspects.

Comment: @ColleenV In my opinion as well, but everyone have their own boundaries

Answer (score 1):

### Always keep in mind Incentives and Motivations!

The Recruiter, at this point, *isn't really on your side*.  Their incentive/motivation is to get a commission check from placing you at a new job.  They couldn't care less about your salary or the missing perk - which is why the first thing they did was indicate that your rejection was a "problem".

It's important to understand this.  Because the recruiter is likely going to try to get you to compromise in some fashion in order to make the placement occur - that's a whole lot easier than renegotiating with the company.

**Only take the job if it's the job you want!** You're not obligated to accept any offer that a company gives you.  Don't let an employer or recruiter pressure or make you feel guilty about turning something down!

#### Moving Forward:

Decide what is a requisite for working there.  What perks are needed, what salary is needed, etc.  If an offer doesn't hit the prerequisites, then don't accept.  Clearly communicate the required perks to the recruiter/employer...

... but *don't* communicate the actual salary requisite.  Remember the incentives?  The recruiter doesn't get paid more if they negotiate you a larger salary.  They simply get paid if both parties say 'Yes' - so if you tell the recruiter "I'd require $80k/year for salary", the recruiter's going to immediately negotiate for exactly $80k/year - even if you could've got more.  Instead, treat the recruiter exactly the same as the employer when it comes to salary negotiation (so any advice about 'salary negotiation' will apply to what you tell the recruiter.)